# Zooming pictures doesn't work on screen of size: 480 x 800 pixels / 4.0 inch

Tags: android, zooming

This method working properly for the higher version of android phone but the same code not worked for the old version phone.

I have override scrollview class when I drag the image from the top the scrollY value going to negative, the image zoom is work properly.

```
@Override
public void BounceOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX,
boolean clampedY) {
    int currentItem = bigProductPic.getCurrentItem();
    try {
        int tempHeight = (int) (bigPicHeight - scrollY);
        RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) bigProductPic.findViewWithTag("myview" + currentItem);
        if(item != null){
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.img);
            Drawable img = imgView.getDrawable();
            int rightBound = (int)(bigPicHeight - tempHeight)/2;


            Log.d("Bounds Before", img.getBounds().flattenToString());
            img.setBounds(rightBound,0,tempHeight+rightBound,tempHeight);
            Log.d("Bounds After", img.getBounds().flattenToString());

            Log.d("Height Before", imgView.getLayoutParams().height+"");
            imgView.getLayoutParams().height = tempHeight;
            Log.d("Height After", imgView.getLayoutParams().height+"");

            imgView.setImageDrawable(img);
            bigProductPic.setY(scrollY);
            Log.d("Product Height Before", bigProductPic.getLayoutParams().height+"");
            bigProductPic.getLayoutParams().height = tempHeight;
            Log.d("Product Height After", bigProductPic.getLayoutParams().height+"");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Error in expanding", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only questions are unlikely to get any answer. Please read this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Elaborate your question properly

Comment: please give the answer. i have no idea of this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your Android API on your old phone. In case it's lower than the SDK you have used for the program it might cause problems.

Just download the right Android SDK for your older device and adopt your code accordingly.
(You can download everything in the Android SDK Manager)

Afterwards you might have to rewrite your code, because the older versions of Android most likely don't support your way of zooming.